# 2d Physics enegine for xna 4

Tags: c#, xna, physics

What is the best 2d physics engine for xna 4.0 in your opinion ? Farseer don't work at all on my vs2010 :/

Comment: I upgraded farseer to visual studio 2010, changed all the references to XNA4, and it all worked perfectly. I'm using the system right now!

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Box 2D](http://box2dxna.codeplex.com/). I haven't used it with XNA, but the C++ library is very nice.

Comment: Seconded.  Box2D for XNA is great.